# Find strings start with alpha except multi specific characters

Tags: r, regex, grepl

Target to find 1st & 2nd elements which start with alpha except "H" or "G"**

```
DD <- c("DD2123","QD2123","HC12231","HCEF","GC2123","1232","--",NA)

grepl("^[[:alpha:]][^H|G]",DD)
```

Found all start with alpha including "H" and "G".

How can I achieve this ?

`grepl("^D|Q",DD)` is not what I need, actual data has other alpha patterns.

Comment: If  :  grepl("^[A-F]|[I-Z]",DD)   is the only best answer , my question no more a question

Comment: Why not use [A-FI-Z] instead of adding all alphabets and then exclude characters

Comment: How about [`^[^HG[:alpha:]]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5eHG%5b%3aalpha%3a%5d%5d&i=DD2123%0d%0aQD2123%0d%0aHC12231%0d%0aHCEF%0d%0aGC2123%0d%0a--%0d%0a&o=m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a PCRE regex like `^(?![HG])\p{L}` or `^(?![HG])[[:alpha:]]`:

```
> DD <- c("DD2123","QD2123","HC12231","HCEF","GC2123","1232","--",NA)
> grepl("^(?![HG])\\p{L}",DD, perl=TRUE)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or `^[^\\P{L}HG]`:

```
> grepl("^[^\\P{L}HG]",DD, perl=TRUE)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The `^(?![HG])[[:alpha:]]` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![HG])` - no `H` or `G` is allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `[[:alpha:]]` or `\p{L}` - a letter.

The `^[^\P{L}HG]` matches the start of a string (`^`) and then matches any char other than a non-letter, `H` and `G`.

Comment: Thats exactly i wanted , make use of perl style version bring a lot of flexibilities .

Answer (score 3):

Just as an alternative. Wiktors solution is more general and practical.

```
grepl("^[a-zA-FI-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]+$",DD)
```

You could define a class of values that are allowed to appear in the first place and then define the following positions.

---

If everything else is allowed to follow, simply use:

```
grepl("^[a-zA-FI-Z]",DD)
```

Comment: Really plain method to solve the similar situation thank you